# Drupal 6 import/export book

Tags: nodes

I'm looking for a module to export/migrate a books (with all child pages) from a Drupal ( 6.x) Installation to another.

Thank you in advance for your kind replies

Answer (score 1):

The module [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) is the most versatile Drupal tool for database migration.

However, book module migration is still not trivial.  Books are nodes, so they can inherit most of their migration from a common class.  But to preserve book node hierarchy that is stored within menu links, you need to use special code  to migrate the hierarchy.  Here is a sketch of the required workflow:

- Migrate nodes as normal.
- Get hierarchy from the source database `book` table, and weights from the `menu_links` table.
- Place a `public function complete()` in your `Migration` class to call `_book_update_outline()` to migrate the hierarchy.

A more detailed receipe, with a special code example, is at [Drupal.org: Book node migration](http://drupal.org/node/1513766).